# How to get sync return from ExecuteScriptAsync in WebView2

Tags: .net, winforms, async-await, webview2

.NET, WinForms.

The calls are triggered from the UI thread (buttons - clicks). The returns from ExecuteScriptAsync should continue to be processed synchronously, i.e. they should be synchronized again with the call context. I fail here.

I tried for example:

```
private void buttonTest1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show(GetMathResult());
    }

    String GetMathResult() {
        // a) Application freezes
        //var result = webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("Math.sin(Math.PI/2)").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        //return result;

        // b) return null
        //String result = null;
        //Task task = new Task(async () => { result = await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("Math.sin(Math.PI/2)"); }); 
        //task.RunSynchronously();
        //return result;

        // c) Excepion: // InvalidCastException: Das COM-Objekt des Typs "System.__ComObject" kann nicht in den Schnittstellentyp "Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.Raw.ICoreWebView2Controller" umgewandelt werden. Dieser Vorgang konnte nicht durchgeführt werden, da der QueryInterface-Aufruf an die COM - Komponente für die Schnittstelle mit der IID "{4D00C0D1-9434-4EB6-8078-8697A560334F}" aufgrund des folgenden Fehlers nicht durchgeführt werden konnte: Schnittstelle nicht unterstützt(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80004002(E_NOINTERFACE)).
        //String result = Task.Run(() => GetMathResultTask()).Result;
        //return result;
    }

    Task<String> GetMathResultTask() {
        return webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("Math.sin(Math.PI/2)");
    }
```

And that doesn't work either (see error):

```
private void buttonTest3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show(Y());
    }

    String Y() {
        String result = null;
        var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try {
                result = await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("Math.sin(Math.PI/2)");
            }
            catch (Exception exc) {
                // !!! {"Das COM-Objekt des Typs \"System.__ComObject\" kann nicht in den Schnittstellentyp \"Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.Raw.ICoreWebView2Controller\" umgewandelt werden. Dieser Vorgang konnte nicht durchgeführt werden, da der QueryInterface-Aufruf an die COM-Komponente für die Schnittstelle mit der IID \"{4D00C0D1-9434-4EB6-8078-8697A560334F}\" aufgrund des folgenden Fehlers nicht durchgeführt werden konnte: Schnittstelle nicht unterstützt (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."}
                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString()); 
            }
            finally {
                autoResetEvent.Set();
            }
        });
        autoResetEvent.WaitOne();

        return result;
    }
```

I am bidding for a code sample.

Comment: Like any other asycn method, use await.

Comment: I think I tried everything as suggested in the link below and it doesn't work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously

Comment: Update the question and add what you tried and what didn't work. `it doesn't work` isn't a problem description. You don't need complicated tricks to await an asynchronous method and get any results. `var result=await whatever.ExecuteScriptAsync(....);`

Comment: After `await` finishes you'll be back in the UI thread. So what does ` I fail here.` mean? Did you try executing the call inside `Task.Run` perhaps, or from another thread?

Comment: Don't forget, I cannot return the result from the method after the "var result = await whatever.ExecuteScriptAsync (....)".

Comment: `private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(await GetMathResultTask());
}`

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei: I need a method with a return value

Answer (score 9):

To get the result from [`ExecuteScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.executescriptasync?view=WebView2-dotnet-1.0.664.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) use [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) operator, like this:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await this.webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
}
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("Math.sin(Math.PI/2)");
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

**Note:** For those who want to use [`WebView2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2?view=WebView2-dotnet-1.0.664.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), you need to have [WebView2 Runtime](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [Microsoft Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) installed on your machine. You also need to install [WebView2 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) in your project.

Comment: Thanks! I can do that. Where I fail is creating a return method. Based on their example:
async String GetMathResult() {
  var result = await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("Math.sin(Math.PI/2)");
  return result;
}

Comment: @SergejLoos what you typed works, once you change it to `async Task<string>`. What's the problem? What did you actually try?

Comment: I edited my question. Hopefully it has become more understandable

Comment: @SergejLoos I was searching for something and I stumbled on this post, which doesn't have an accepted answer. JFYI, you can accept your own answer as well; however, I believe this answer is a much better approach comparing to the other solutions (including your own answer) :) - Anyhow, marking an answer as accepted, highlights it for future readers as *probably* a reliable solution.

Answer (score 5):

I will probably have to use it that way. This is the best solution I could find:

```
private void buttonTest3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        GetMathResult_v3((x) => {
            MessageBox.Show(x);
            // .. 
        });
    }

    void GetMathResult_v3(Action<String> callbackAction) {

        var task = webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("Math.sin(Math.PI/2)");

        task.ContinueWith(
            (x) => {
                String mathResult = x.Result;
                callbackAction(mathResult);
            }
            , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Anyone working with WebView2 under WinForms and looking for Safe, Simple and Anti-Blocking Solution these lines of codes may seem logical:

```
public void WaitAsyncTask(int waitSecond, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter activeTask)
{
    double secondDiffer = (DateTime.Now - WaitStartTime).TotalSeconds;
    while (secondDiffer < waitSecond)
    {
        secondDiffer = (DateTime.Now - WaitStartTime).TotalSeconds;
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (activeTask.IsCompleted)
            break;
    }
}
```

*WaitStartTime* is user defined and assigned before *Async* process start.

To call this method from main method:

```
public async Task ExecJavaScript(string userScript)
{
    MacroJava = "";
    var tr = await ((Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2)wbSelectedTech).CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(userScript);
    MacroJava = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(tr);
    MacroJava = MacroJava is null ? "" : MacroJava.ToString();
}
```

Now call these helper methods from this method:

```
public string GetelementValue(string elmId)
{
   var aw = ExecJavaScript("document.getElementById('" + elmId + "').innerHTML").GetAwaiter();
   TimeWaitStart = DateTime.Now;
   WaitAsyncTask(2, aw);//for 2 seconds maximum 
   return MacroJava.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used my own solution which worked for me, but I don't know if it can cause any problems in the future (if someone knows, please add comment). It waits 2 seconds for script to execute before jumping out:

```
int max_count = 200;
var task = webView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
while (!task.IsCompleted && --max_count > 0)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
}
if (max_count > 0)
{
    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(task.Result)?.ToString() ?? "";
}
else
{
    // Timeout
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("Math.sin(Math.PI/2)").Result;
```

Comment: this does not working