# Task doesn't run in GUI, but OK in console

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, task

I am using a third-party library.  That library contains an object with an `async` method that returns `Task<SomeStuff>`.  I am wrapping that object and others into my own class.  My wrapper method is also `async` and has the same return.  Calling the wrapper method works fine in my unit tests and a console app.  However, it doesn't work in my WPF GUI app.  I have tried different methods for invoking in my GUI but nothing works.

In my unit tests, I invoke with `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.  However, in my GUI this never returns.

I tried using `Start()` but that results in an error: "Start may not be called on a promise-style task."

What do I need to do to make this work in my GUI?

```
            // Foo() returns Task<SomeStuff>

            // this works fine in unit test as well as console app, but not in GUI (WPF)
            SomeStuff stuff = myWrapper.Foo().GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            // this results in error: "Start may not be called on a promise-style task."
            Task<SomeStuff> myTask = myWrapper.Foo();
            myTask.Start();
            myTask.Wait();
```

Comment: Never use `GetResult()` or `Result` or anything like that. Use `await` instead.

Comment: "Never use" doesn't help me much.  Perhaps an explanation of why you think it is a bad idea would help.  It works fine for me except for the situation I described.  In addition, I am not sure await is a solution to my problem.  Wouldn't I have to mark my method as async and all the methods that call it.  Isn't that what GetAwaiter is for?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good discussion of various approaches to my issue here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously?rq=1][1]

For the moment I resolved my issue as below.  I shall re-read the post from the link and perhaps refine my approach.

```
            Task<SomeStuff> task = Task.Run(() => myWrapper.Foo());

            task.Wait();

            SomeStuff stuff = task.Result;
```