How to properly wait on multiple I/O tasks with individual exception handling?
I need to send multiple HTTP-calls (httpclient.SendAsync()) from a synchronous method (cannot be async!) in parallel and then wait for them all. Another requirement is: I have to individually handle exceptions. That means, I must know which task caused which exception to sort them right.
My solution till now:
var listOfRequests = new List<int>()
 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

var tasks = new Dictionary<int, Task<SomeData>>();

//start all tasks
foreach (var curr in listOfRequests)
{
    tasks.Add(curr.Key, httpclient.GetSomeDataFromEndpoint(curr));
}

//wait for all tasks to complete
foreach (var currTask in tasks)
{
    try
    {
        currTask.Value.Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle individual exception
    }
}

I know, this is not best practice, but how would I achieve this with Task.WhenAll()?
I came up with this idea, but it also looks not too nice...
try
{
    // Wait for all tasks to complete synchronously
    Task.WhenAll(tasks.Values).Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //do nothing, because exceptions are handled below
}
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    if (task.Value.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Success: {task.Key} - Status: {task.Value.IsCompleted}");
    }
    else if (task.Value.IsFaulted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {task.Key} - Message: {task.Value.Exception}");
    }
    else
    {
        //maybe task was cancelled
    }
}

Environment/Requirements:

.NET Framework 4.8
Library that MUST offer synchronous methods (because callers cannot handle async)
must individually catch exceptions and sort to task
I thought all tasks are already started when I add them to the dictionary (as I saw on Asynchronous programming scenarios - Wait for multiple tasks to complete), but it seems that my http calls are send sequentially to the API (I see this in the API log), so I thought maybe something with my client code and the way I wait on this tasks might be wrong...

Thanks in advance!!

Regarding your last bullet point: this depends on how GetSomeDataFromEndpoint is implemented. Can you show the essential parts of it?

Why don't you use await Task.WhenAll(....) ? Both snippets are bad. All the tasks are completed after WhenAll anyway so there's no need to check IsCompleted. On top of that, there are better ways to execute multiple HTTP calls with proper exception handling and logging, eg using Parallel.ForEachAsyn and *catching and reporting errors inside the lambda itself`. This allows you to control the number of concurrent calls and report problems while you still have access to the request and response

If you need enclosing method to be synchron, you have to use Task.Run, Task.Run(() => httpclient.GetSomeDataFromEndpoint(curr)). Otherwise you may have deadlock.

MUST BE synchron! why? What are you actually trying to do? There are better ways, like using Parallel.ForEachAsync or Dataflow classes like TransformBlock and ActionBlock to make multiple parallel calls and process the results in parallel. Both of which would parallelize even a GetSomeDataFromEndpoint with synchronous code, unless there's explicit locking

I thought all tasks are already started you didn't post the code that starts the tasks, only code that puts them in a list

"I know, this is not best practice," -- How do you know this? I see no reason for your code not being a good practice. It satisfies the requirements that you specified in the question, which is waiting synchronously, handling the exceptions sequentially and in order, and imposing no concurrency limitation whatsoever. People don't do every day this exact thing, so there is no much established theory or practice about how to do it.

KlausGütter: This is just a wrapper method with a httpclient.SendAsync in it.
TheodorZoulias: Thank you for you kind words :)
@others: I have to use synchronous methods, because I develop a library to use for some callers who are technically not able to call a async method. Second, Using Task.Run / Task Parallel Libray for I/O bound tasks is not recommended by microsoft
Thank you all for your replies. See my solutions below

Thank you for all your comments and answers!
My problems was, that those http calls seemed to be not sent in parallel. Root cause was not the way I handled the tasks (although I know it is not the nicest way, but I cannot find a better way for my requirements), but a simple default setting of the http client concurrent connections, which only applies for .net framework and somehow NOT for .net core.
So this line
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

was the solution to my problem.

If your enclosing method has to be non-async a quick hack could be to wrap all this code in proper async method using await Task.WhenAll() and call it with .GetAwaiter.GetResult(), however it's also not the best approach, it has been explained by many people already, please have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39371523/9855767

Thank you, yes I know. But how would I individually catch the possible exception from each task and sort them right?
Thanks for sharing the link, very interesting
